# Check if a value is inside a sql String field with many values

Tags: string, sql-server-2005, contains

I have a sql field with values like "test had, that , much never";

I want to know wether "had" is in that list if yes return the whole datarow.

There was a sql server function like "In" Select value in (fieldname)...

anyone can tell me, thanks :)

p.s. dont want to use the "like" which is slow.

Comment: I don't think you should blame `like` for being slow. You should point the finger at a lack of index instead. Solution is to **not** store many values in one string field but in a separate table that has an index that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `LIKE` consider Full Text Indexing and the `CONTAINS` statement instead.

Comment: Which also makes it easy to discriminate between "had" and "haddock"